# Android blacklist wifi bssid

Tags: android, wifi, bssid

I have a problem banning a specific bssid. I can see there is a class called WifiNative that was in api 19 but not able to access it:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiNative.java

Is there any other way anyone knows of to do this? Maybe via JNI? Any android system libraries that can be used? c,c++?

Answer (score -2):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
newWifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

from there you can get the BSSID by doing

```
newWifiInfo.getBSSID()
```

then "blacklist" by turning off the wifi via

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false)
```

Also don't forget your permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

If you want more control over your wifi state, you can use the following library to "sniff" your connection and other things

https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork

Comment: I dont think this blacklists the specific bssid. Also one ssid might have two bssids. How to disable one specific bssid but be able to connect to the other one?